# Create a SQL query to retrieve data from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables :

`T_STOCK`: primary key is `id`, `seller`, and some others fields let say `a` and `b`.
`T_FLOW`: primary key is (`id` + `startdate`), and some others fields, for example `c` and `d`.

I want a query that returns all the columns for each records from `T_STOCK` regarding a specific `seller`, but completed with the columns (`startDate`, `c` and `d`) from the `T_FLOW` table.

The relation between `T_STOCK` and `T_FLOW` is based on the `id` attribute.
Everytime a record with a specific ID exists in `T_STOCK`, at least one record exist in `T_FLOW` for this ID.

However, it may happen that more than one record exist in `T_FLOW`. In this case, I must consider only the **most recent one** (i.e. the one with `max(startDate)`).

In others words, if we have the following tables content:

```
+---------------------+
|       T_STOCK       |
+----+--------+---+---+
| ID | SELLER | a | b |
+----+--------+---+---+
| 01 | foobar | 1 | 2 |
+----+--------+---+---+
| 02 | foobar | 3 | 4 |
+----+--------+---+---+
| 03 | foobar | 5 | 6 |
+----+--------+---+---+

+---------------------------+
|           T_FLOW          |
+----+------------+----+----+
| ID |  StartDate |  c |  d |
+----+------------+----+----+
| 01 | 01/01/2010 |  7 |  8 |
+----+------------+----+----+
| 02 | 01/01/2010 |  9 | 10 |
+----+------------+----+----+
| 02 | 07/01/2010 | 11 | 12 |
+----+------------+----+----+
| 03 | 03/01/2010 | 13 | 14 |
+----+------------+----+----+
| 03 | 05/01/2010 | 15 | 16 |
+----+------------+----+----+
```

The result of the query must be :

```
+----+--------+---+---+------------+----+----+
| ID | SELLER | a | b |  startDate |  c |  d |
+----+--------+---+---+------------+----+----+
| 01 | foobar | 1 | 2 | 01/01/2010 |  7 |  8 |
+----+--------+---+---+------------+----+----+
| 02 | foobar | 3 | 4 | 03/01/2010 | 11 | 12 |
+----+--------+---+---+------------+----+----+
| 03 | foobar | 5 | 6 | 01/01/2010 | 15 | 16 |
+----+--------+---+---+------------+----+----+
```

How do I write my query then?

Comment: Your relationship seems a little bit weird to me. Your stock `PK` is `(id, seller)` and you can have two stocks with the same `id`, but flows are related by `id` only. Is it intentional?

Comment: @Quassnoi, yes, it is intentional :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_stock s
JOIN    (
        SELECT  f.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startDate DESC) AS rn
        FROM    t_flow f
        ) f
ON      f.id = s.id
        AND f.rn = 1
```

Here's a solution that does not use the analytic functions:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_stock s
JOIN    t_flow f
ON      (f.id, f.startDate) =
        (
        SELECT  id, MAX(startDate)
        FROM    t_flow fi
        WHERE   fi.id = s.id
        GROUP BY
                id
        )
```

Comment: Is there any solution to write this query without using `row_number() over (partition ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

You get the most recent T_FLOW record using analytics, [as shown by Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071152/create-a-sql-query-to-retrieve-data-from-two-tables/2071169#2071169), or using:

```
select id, max(startdate) last_start_date from t_flow group by id;
```

You can then join this with your T_STOCK table - something like:

```
select
    s.*,
    f.*
from
    t_stock s
        inner join t_flow f on
                f.id = s.id
            and (f.id, f.startdate) in
                (
                select
                    id,
                    max(startdate) laststartdate
                from
                    t_flow
                group by
                    id
                )
```

Comment: You need one more join to get the other columns from `t_flow`.

Comment: This should be `(f.id, f.startdate) IN …`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        s.*
       ,FIRST_VALUE(f.startdate)
        OVER (PARTITION BY f.id ORDER BY f.startdate DESC) startdate
       ,FIRST_VALUE(f.c)
        OVER (PARTITION BY f.id ORDER BY f.startdate DESC) c
       ,FIRST_VALUE(f.d)
        OVER (PARTITION BY f.id ORDER BY f.startdate DESC) d
FROM    t_stock s, t_flow f
WHERE   f.id = s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, max(startdate) last_start_date from t_flow group by id;
```

Then you can join this with your `T_STOCK` table, something like this:

```
select s.*, f.* from t_stock s inner join t_flow f on f.id = s.id
and (f.id, f.startdate) in (select id, max(startdate) laststartdate
                from t_flow group by id)
```